# Checking a calculation with mean curvature and second fundamental form

Tags: proof-verification, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a 3 dimensional manifold, $N$ a surface in $M$ and $A$ the second fundamental form on $N$, $H$ the mean curvature. $h$ is the metric induced on $N$.

I need to show that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{N_l}|A - \frac{H}{2}h|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\int_{N_l}(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)^2.
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ with respect to $h$.

This is what I tied:
In matrix form, we get
\begin{equation*}
A =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \hspace{0.5cm} \text{and $H = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2.$}
\end{equation*}
We can express $h$ as the following (with an appropriate basis)
\begin{equation*}
h =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have 
\begin{equation*}
A-\frac{H}{2}h =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\lambda_1 -\lambda_2}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{equation*}
and $|A-\frac{H}{2}h|^2 = \frac{1}{4}(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)^2$. If the calculation is correct then I am wrong by a factor 1/2... What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are making, for some reason not clear to me, a mistake when calculating the squared norm of $A-\frac{H}{2}h$. This is just, using your matrix representation, $$\left(\frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}\right)^2 +  \left(\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2}\right)^2 = 2\frac{1}{4}\left({\lambda_2-\lambda_1}\right)^2$$

Comment: I think I got confused on the definition of the norm of a matrix. Could you just state the definition here, just to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: @Sasha The norm induced by the scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is simply $||( a_{ij} )||^2 = \sum_{ij} a_{ij}^2$